# Meteor - Error: no such package: 'blaze'

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

While working on meteor I suddenly found this error

```
            quackadmin@quack:~/quack$ sudo meteor
            [[[[[ ~/quack ]]]]]

            => Started proxy.
            => Meteor 0.8.3 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
            => Started MongoDB.
            => Errors prevented startup:

            While building package `iron-dynamic-template`:
            error: no such package: 'blaze'

            => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

It seems someone suddenly did an update on the iron-package and broke it. Anyone know how to resolve this. I spent ages on this and now can't get through this error.

I tried setting a manual version but that doesn't seem to work as well. Meteor has so much undocumented magic going on.

Answer (score 8):

Iron Router 0.8.1 needs Meteor 0.8.3 to work.

To fix this just run:

```
meteor update
```

This updates the project to use Meteor 0.8.3 (the current release as at the time of this answer)

Comment: @noj Could you post up your `smart.lock`, `.meteor/release` and `.meteor/packages`

Answer (score 2):

Meteor just had an update yesterday (0.8.3).

Along with that they changed a some things in iron-router and blaze...

Just running `meteor update` should work, or if you really wanted too (and I'm assuming you installed blaze through meteorite) you can manually uninstall it by using `mrt uninstall blaze` and then check with `mrt` and then `mrt add blaze` again.

I think this should work, but I'm still new to this stuff so forgive me if I'm wrong....

Good Luck :)

-------- UPDATE -------

Meteor just updated and the Meteorite package is now built in and your packages should auto update.  If you are still seeing this problem search for it by using

```
meteor search [Package]
```

try searching for blaze now, I found it.

Here is the link for more information:
https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/26/meteor-090-new-packaging-system

Comment: mrt add blaze throws an error saying no such package exists :(

Comment: Im seeing the same issue, even after update to 0.8.3